# AngularJS and typescript broadcast

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, broadcast

I have following problem. I want to broadcast array of albums to another controller. Structure of my controllers : 
 Parent - multimediaController, child - multimediaAlbumController. I am sending variable, but i cannot receive i, don't know why actually..

**multimediaController.ts**

```
export class MultimediaController {
   $scope;
   static $inject = ['$scope'];
   constructor($scope){
     this.$scope = $scope;
   }
   changeAlbum(){
       this.$scope.$broadcast('prod', console.log("sending") );
   }
}
```

**multimediaAlbumController.ts**

```
export class MultimediaAlbumController{
   $scope;
   static $inject = ['$scope'];
   constructor($scope){ 
      this.$scope = $scope;
   }
   brodRec(){
     this.$scope.$on('prod', () => {
            console.log("receiving");
        });
   }
}
```

i am getting in console - sengind, but cannot get receiving. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: When / where are you calling `brodRec`? I'd just move the `$scope.$on` call into the constructor

Comment: So just try to move $scope.$on to construcotr, ye? Will try

Comment: Ok works. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

please make $scope variable public.

```
constructor(public scope:ng<IScope>) {
 this.$scope = scope;
}
```